# String literal in C program, can it be found in binary?

Tags: c

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
  if (strncmp(argv[1], "password")) {
    printf("Incorrect password\n");   
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Can I disassemble the binary for this compiled program and see the string "password" somewhere in the binary or is it only visible during run-time?

Comment: Yes, and most of the time it's not even that hard.

Comment: It will be visible in the binary.

Comment: it will be in (depending on compiler) the .const section or the .rodata section.  output a .map file to find the offset/address of those sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, yes. Moreover, you don't need to "disassemble" anything. Most of the time you will be able to see it right in the compiled binary by opening it in a text or hex editor.

Comment: Exactly, you just dump the file content, and it will be there. `strings` utiliity from `binutils` will filter the non printable data and show the strings only.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII strings do not undergo any special encoding/decoding, so they appear literally in the binary and will appear when the binary is interpreted as a (mostly garbage-y-looking) ASCII file. If you think about it more deeply, the only systematic alternative to storing them in the binary would be some horrible OS-wide central registry of all strings for all programs. If they were stored in a separate file they could get separated from the binary.

However, the OP seems to beg a larger question about code layout and just what compilation does with read-only data such as strings. A more educational way to 'find' the string is to see the intermediate compilation stage of human-readable assembly, where the string will be laid out and referenced by a label. The linker (next compilation stage) will then resolve the label to a numeric offset from the beginning of the binary. Note the `.rodata` ("read-only data section") label below.

From the gcc manpage:
    -S  Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble.  The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.

Results:

```
    .file   "foo.c"
    .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "password"
.LC1:
    .string "Incorrect password"
    .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
```

[assembly language instructions follow]